# python delete next and previous rows from textfile. Based on sample

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to delete the specified rows from textfile and the previous and next rows.
I can delete the specified row, but I don't know how can I delete the next and the previous.
Here is my code

```
def Parser(line):
global destination
if "CHECKIN" in line:
    splitted = line.split()
    destination = open(ea_xml_dest,'r')
    lines = destination.readlines()
    destination = open(ea_xml_dest,'w')
    sample = str(splitted[5][:-1])
    for i in lines:
        if sample not in i:
            destination.write(i)
    destination.close()
    destination = open(ea_xml_dest,'r')
```

This script not move the lines what contains the sample into the new file 
How can I avoid the previous and the next lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must find the index of the line with the searched `substr`
and save it to the variable (`found`).
Than you take from the original `lines` all to the line ''before'':
and all after the line ''after''.

```
found = None
for i,s in enumerate(lines):
  if substr in s:
    found = i
    break

if found: 
  lines = lines[:found-1] + lines[found+2:]
```

If nothing was found, you just leave the `lines` variable as it is.

Comment: next element after found will not be deleted
    lines = lines[:found-1] + lines[found+2:]

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only part of the code you can change, then you're going to have to do something pretty messy.

If you have more flexibility, then you could do something like this:

```
with open("lines.dat","r") as f:

  previousLine = ""
  lines = []
  checkinCounter = 1

  for line in f:

    if checkinCounter > 0:
      checkinCounter -= 1

    elif "CHECKIN" in line:
      checkinCounter = 2

    else:
      lines.append(previousLine.strip())

    previousLine = line

print lines
```

where `lines.dat` is

```
1
2
3
4
5
CHECKIN
6
7
8
9
CHECKIN
10
11
12
23
24
156146
```

the output is `['1', '2', '3', '4', '7', '8', '11', '12', '23', '24', '156146']`

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('in.txt') as in_file:
    it = iter(in_file)
    prev = None
    line = it.next()
    while line:
        next = iter.next()
        # condition goes here
        # if line found ....
        prev = line
        line = next
```